# How do you get a checkbox/radio to be selected upon click of the word next to it?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have a large form that has all 50 states listed as checkboxes. Instead of having the user click JUST the checkbox to select it (as well as radios), how can I get the checkbox to be selected by clicking the word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `label` HTML element like so:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" /> My label here</label>
```

You can also tie the label to an HTML control that has an ID with the `for` attribute, if you don't want to nest the elements. Here's an example of that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" />
<label for="my-checkbox">My Label</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a label element which is for the checkbox:

```
<label for="check">Checkbox label</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
```

You can click the label and it will toggle the checkbox.